# Academic Degree dilemma

Tags: story, knowledge

On a leisure day, I had the following conversation with my friend.

**My friend**: "Dude! I noticed that almost all the abbreviations of academic degrees which are meant for Bachelors have format of B.... such as B.Sc, B.Com, B.Tech, ...and all these have their corresponding  Masters degrees whose abbreviations start with M ( such as M.Sc, M.Com, M.Tech...)...and wondering whether there is any exception for it..."?

**Me**: "Well, I do not see any exceptions....wait...it seems there is one..."

**My Friend**: "What do you mean? You got any"?

**Me**: "Yes, there is one. There is one Bachelor's degree whose abbreviation starts with M."

**My Friend**: "Oh! Great!! Any clues to get it"

**Me**: " I feel it is specific to few countries/notation that is followed. Even perhaps more could be possible, though the one I got is more obvious".

Can you please help my friend to find out such a degree.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a trivia question and not a puzzle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

> MBBS

This is because it’s full form is

> Medicinae Baccalaureus, Baccalaureus Chirurgiae (Latin for Bachelor of Medicine, Bachelor to surgery (from Google Translate))